# twitter boostrap css displaying differently when pushed

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get the css recognised as '.jumbotron h1' or '.jumbatron .lead'

```
<div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Thousands of clinical guidelines!</h1><br>
            <p class="lead">GuidelinesForMe is a free, crowd-sourced database with links to online clinical treatment guidelines. It currently has <%= Guideline.all.count %> guidelines.</p>
                <%= link_to main_path, class: "btn btn-large btn-success" do%>
                                See all guidelines


<% end %>
      </div>
```

but it's inside a div with the class 'jumbotron' but the `<h1>` itself is only being shown as h1, and not 'jumbotron h1' - this is the same problem for the `<p>` etc. too

Something is overriding it but I'm not sure how to work out what...

```
my_styles.css is 

/* Main marketing message and sign up button */
.jumbotron {
  margin: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.jumbotron h1 {
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 1;
}
.jumbotron .lead {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1.25;
}
.jumbotron .btn {
  font-size: 21px;
  padding: 14px 24px;
}
```

and my application.css is

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require bootstrap-responsive
 *= require guidelines
 *= require my_styles

 */
```

Comment: if you *= require_tree . you dont need to call individual stylesheets, you can call them all at once, as for your issue is everything working locally? also i think your require_self is in the wrong place, should be at the end, well before require_tree

Comment: Do you have an example site / fiddle? Very hard to help with "Something is overriding it" when we can't see it.

Comment: yes you are right, sorry.  I think it's an issue with my css 'requires'.  I will have another look and post again.